# Is there a way to use Splinter to screenshot a browser view directly into memory?

Tags: python-3.x, headless-browser, splinter

The intended way to take a screenshot via Splinter is pretty straightforward, and I understand that in the context of mimicking a web-browser a screenshot basically means saving an image to a file, but I was wondering if I could throw away that IO concern by directly reading the screenshot into a Python PIL object when I invoke `browser.screenshot()` . The reason for this is that I would perform some processing on the image regardless so saving it to disk and reading it from disk seems like a step I could short-circuit.

```
browser = Browser()
screenshot_path = browser.screenshot('absolute_path/your_screenshot.png')
```

Something like

```
screenshot_pil = browser.screenshot('path_to', inmemory=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I missed this in the documentation, but there is a function [screenshot_as_png()](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/9a79baf73f10d79e9b3d7695745c937154018874/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py#L978) that seems to do what I want but I'm not sure how to access it through the namespace of a Browser object